# Trying to call a service which plays looping background music at the load of splash screen Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an app in which there should be looping background music.The first activity is a Splash screen.I have created a service as shown below:

```
package com.igloo.footballultimate;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        player.start();

        return 1;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO



    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

I am calling the service in the oncreate of the splash screen as:

```
Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
        startService(svc);
```

But i dont hear the music playing.Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to add

```
mediaplayer.perpare()
```

Comment: Where would you suggest me to add it?I am new to android.

Comment: Before you start playing you need to prepare first. Have a look at diagram in [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: Also in order to play a music while splash screen is showing you do not need a service. you can do it in the activity

Comment: There are multiple activities and i need the music to loop and persist across all activities.

Comment: leave some log messages in onStartCommand and onStart and see which one is called

Comment: Also make sure your phone is not in silent. sometime the setVolume does not work

Comment: I put breakpoints in the on start and onstartcommand , they are not called.But in the oncreate of the splashscreen i have called the service using intent.Why is the service not being called?

Comment: I declared it in the manifest.Still not playing .it hits the onstartcommand.